# Failed to install airflow with pip

Tags: python, pip, airflow

pip command:

```
pip install google-cloud-storage apache-beam[gcp]==2.2.0 apache-airflow[gcp_api]==1.9.0 paramiko sshtunnel
```

Error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/cyao/Project/itcorp-airflow/venv/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-8hamva8l/apache-airflow/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-8hamva8l/apache-airflow/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-8hamva8l/apache-airflow/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-8hamva8l/apache-airflow/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-8hamva8l/apache-airflow/setup.py", line 102
        async = [
              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, add some description and some context! Help us help you! In the future please avoid posting just an error stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code from [apache-airflow `setup.py`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/d760d63e1a141a43a4a43daee9abd54cf11c894b/setup.py#L102) from version 1.9.0. In Python 3.7 the word `async` became [a reserved keyword](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html#summary-release-highlights) so the code is incompatible with Python 3.7+.

Either use Python 3.6 or use later version of `apache-airflow`.